# Why does my SQL query fail when I use quotes?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

Hi I want to write sql query in MVC4? I will explain my issue clearly

**Sql Query**

```
 Select * from View_VisitorsForm  where VisitingDate>='' and VisistingDate<=''
```

I tried to write this query in controller but i am getting error. i donno the perfect  syntax to use in controller. My error which is mentioned in the below image.

[image: Query error]

Please any one tell me the correct solution for my problem.

Advance Thanks.

Comment: Look up SQL Injection before doing anything else. But basically you're messing up the " and the ' in your sql / code

Comment: MVC is a web framework. The database API you use is ADO.NET

Comment: the " not yet closed , check the end of the query

Comment: String concatenation is performed with `+` and can't be combined with the bitwise-and operator (&). Did you think that `&` is some special placeholder or delimiter?

Comment: i gave that but still showing error abdul

Comment: remove the = symbol after the BETWEEN clause, also put a space before AND clause (eg .. BETWEEN abc AND pqr ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the following:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from view_VisitorsForm where VisitingDate between " + fromdt + " and " + todt + "",con);
```

Comment: no alas it is working in C# too but i got one doubt im using old technology here .any one tell me the latest one.